# KendoUI: Mix Web and Mobile Widgets in Web Application

Tags: mobile, web, kendo-ui, switch-statement

Has anybody successfully used any of the KendoUI mobile widgets in a Web Application?  I have an site using the Kendo Web library.  I would like to use the Switch widget from the mobile library.

I've added code like this:

```
<div id="mobBody" style="width:50px;height:30px">
 <input id="wink-switch" data-role="view" />
</div>
```

I create the widget as normal:

```
$("#wink-switch").kendoMobileSwitch();
```

The widget actually works at this point, the problem is it is not presented at all correctly.  In order to get it to presnt correctly I need to do:

> var switD = document.getElementById("mobBody");
>
> ```
> var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(switD); </script>
> ```

However this has many undesirable affects on the remainder of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently won't work nicely. The Kendo UI Mobile widgets work only in a Kendo UI Mobile application for now. This behaviour is going to change soon though so you could use the switch widget without a mobile application. This feature will land with the Q1 2014 release which is expected in March 2014.